# Facing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.setDelegateBearerErrorResponseSending with keycloak

Tags: rest, spring-security, jetty, keycloak

We are trying to secure kafka connect rest api , since it uses embedded jetty server and as of now keycloak does not have any plugin adapters we decided to use keycloak-spring-security-adapter. Server is starting normally but while trying to access any resource it is giving 
**HTTP ERROR: 500
  Problem accessing /. Reason:
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.setDelegateBearerErrorResponseSending(Z)V**

Here is a part of my pom.xml :

```xml
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
<version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
<version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my security config

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler() throws Exception {
    return super.keycloakLogoutHandler();
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

}

Here is the code snippet where jetty server is being started.

```java
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    context.addEventListener( new ContextLoaderListener() );
    context.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
    context.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", SecurityConfig.class.getName() );
    context.addFilter( new FilterHolder( new DelegatingFilterProxy( "springSecurityFilterChain" ) ), "/*", EnumSet.allOf( DispatcherType.class ));
    String allowedOrigins = config.getString(WorkerConfig.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_CONFIG);
    if (allowedOrigins != null && !allowedOrigins.trim().isEmpty()) {
        FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(new CrossOriginFilter());
        filterHolder.setName("cross-origin");
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, allowedOrigins);
        String allowedMethods = config.getString(WorkerConfig.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS_CONFIG);
        if (allowedMethods != null && !allowedOrigins.trim().isEmpty()) {
            filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, allowedMethods);
        }
        context.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
    }

    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
    Slf4jRequestLog requestLog = new Slf4jRequestLog();
    requestLog.setLoggerName(RestServer.class.getCanonicalName());
    requestLog.setLogLatency(true);
    requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context, new DefaultHandler(), requestLogHandler});

    /* Needed for graceful shutdown as per `setStopTimeout` documentation */
    StatisticsHandler statsHandler = new StatisticsHandler();
    statsHandler.setHandler(handlers);
    jettyServer.setHandler(statsHandler);
    jettyServer.setStopTimeout(GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_MS);
    jettyServer.setStopAtShutdown(true);

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConnectException("Unable to start REST server", e);
    }
```

Can anyone please help me understand what that error really means?

Adding full error trace while accessing rest resource :

```
 WARN Error for /sso/login (org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler:667)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.setDelegateBearerErrorResponseSending(Z)V
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! - Please edit your question and include more lines of the stacktrace.  The details of who was calling what and when is useful here.  Feel free to censor any sensitive packages/classes/methods in the stacktrace (but leave the lines with references to the various open source libraries you use alone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading version of `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` to 4.0.0 as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

`org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.setDelegateBearerErrorResponseSending()` has been introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/aaac85e5418acd0ac4025a96c51430e735ad7d5b#diff-83b08ff5b601fe9cf55691c4a3325955) since 4.1.0.

You built your module with Keycloak 4.1.0 but probably you are using it with Keycloak 4.0.0 or earlier.

Comment: still facing  same issue :(